# Verify custom connect post message?

Tags: docusignapi

When I receive a Docusign custom connect POST message at my httpS server. How can I verify that it has in fact come from Docusign?

Does docusign have a list of IP addresses that they will send the post message from?

Is there some other recommended method to verify that the POST message was sent by DocuSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to validate that the message is coming from Docusign depending on your requirements.

**See this great Docusign [Blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/) about securing connect webhook listener**

> - Use a Pre-shared Secret
> - Use Mutual TLS to authenticate the client(Docusign)
> - Check the SSL/TLS certificate of the webhook caller (DocuSign).
> - Set DocuSign to digitally sign the data in the notification XML
> - (***Not recommended***)Whitelist Docusign's [IP addresses](https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/) on your server that is listening to the connect messages.

More info [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status)(Scroll to the bottom of the page. There's more section)